# Multiple rows carousel centering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

### Explanation

I'm trying to center a multiple rows carousel ([slick.js](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)), but it doesn't center. As you can see in the code below, I tried to use `.slick-slide{text-align: center !important;}` and set Bootstrap's `text-center` - which is the same of `text-align: center` - to the carousel class, but still, nothing happens.

[image]

### Code

You can also see it in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gqvcn2s0/) and in ["fullscreen mode"](http://jsfiddle.net/gqvcn2s0/embedded/result/).

ps: it's be better to visualize it in fullscreen.

```js
$('.carousel').slick({
    infinite: true,
    arrows: false,
    dots: true,
    slidesPerRow: 3,
    rows: 3
});
```

```css
.carousel-wrapper {
    background-color: rgb(235, 235, 235);
    position: relative;
}

img {
    background-color: black;
}

.slick-slide {
    text-align: center !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick-theme.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.css" />
</head>

<body>

    <section class="carousel-wrapper">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">

                <ul class="col-md-12 carousel text-center">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onedlq.com/wp-content/themes/komodo/img/no-image-140.jpg" alt="">
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onedlq.com/wp-content/themes/komodo/img/no-image-140.jpg" alt="">
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onedlq.com/wp-content/themes/komodo/img/no-image-140.jpg" alt="">
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onedlq.com/wp-content/themes/komodo/img/no-image-140.jpg" alt="">
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onedlq.com/wp-content/themes/komodo/img/no-image-140.jpg" alt="">
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onedlq.com/wp-content/themes/komodo/img/no-image-140.jpg" alt="">
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onedlq.com/wp-content/themes/komodo/img/no-image-140.jpg" alt="">
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onedlq.com/wp-content/themes/komodo/img/no-image-140.jpg" alt="">
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onedlq.com/wp-content/themes/komodo/img/no-image-140.jpg" alt="">
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onedlq.com/wp-content/themes/komodo/img/no-image-140.jpg" alt="">
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onedlq.com/wp-content/themes/komodo/img/no-image-140.jpg" alt="">
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onedlq.com/wp-content/themes/komodo/img/no-image-140.jpg" alt="">
                        </a>
                    </li>

                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Thanks in advance,
Luiz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.slick-slide li a {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Add this centers your image tiles, especially since they are fixed size and smaller than the list item width. This also gives your anchor tags 'layout', which they don't currently have. However, your navigation dots' alignment is a little off as well, FYI.

EDIT: Add this solves the dot alignment.

```
.slick-dots {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Comment: Thanks you!! It worked for the images, but as you said, the dots are still off. Would you know how to fix it? I tried to center it by using `.slick-dots {text-center: center;}`, but nothing happens.

Comment: See my addition above

Answer (score 1):

Reviewing your fiddle code, the width of the "li" element holding the images are 33.33% and that fills up the container making it 3 "li" elements per row. Having said that, the images in them do not fill up the 33.33% width of their parents. SO you need to center them in their containers.
You can try this code below.

```
.carousel-wrapper .slick-slide img{
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

This will be specific to only the slick slider in the ".carousel-wrapper" container

This fixes the dots

```
.carousel-wrapper .slick-dots {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! It solves the images problem, but the dots are still off. Would you know how to fix it? I tried to center it by using `.slick-dots {text-center: center;}`, but nothing happens.

Comment: Since Ryan answered everything before, I'm accepting his answer, but your answer is just as great as his, so I also upvoted yours. Thanks again!!